# android studio not download gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new project with Android studio, gradle can't be downloaded locally, https://services.gradle.org can't be connected. I don't know why, but when I click the gradle link, Mac can download gradle soon,I'll take it You can't delete all the contents in the .gradle folder

Comment: Odds are this won't help you, but if you are talking about gradle is not downloading the libraries from the repositories, make sure you're using secured URLs that use "https" and not just "http".  Some older documentation may still list the http version of the URLs, which generally will not work.
Make sure that gradle is not set to offline mode, which may prevent it from downloading resources, including itself.
Could you include the actual error messages?

Comment: Make sure you connect to internet even you already download gradle at the first time, if you not set your android studio for work offline in the future, you'll always need to internet connection to download gradle in every project. And please add more detail from  logcat

Comment: This is an error that broke out in Android studio. I was able to connect to the network at that time. When I clicked the error, I could download gradle on the browser, but I couldn't download it on Android studio. I don't know what the wrong configuration of Android studio is